# distribution of $\cos(\omega_0 n)$ where n are integers?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Assume we have the sequence $\,x[n]=\cos(\omega_0 n),$ where $n$ are integers.

If we suppose these are realizations of a random variable, what would be the p.d.f. of that random variable?

Comment: I suppose this is quite likely to depend on the value of $\omega_0$. E.g. if $\omega_0 = 2\pi$ it would be rather non-random.

Comment: Also suppose $\omega_0$ has not those exceptional values.

Comment: That is, suppose that $\omega_0$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.  It can be shown that $\{\cos(\omega_0 n):n\in\mathbb N \}$ is dense in $(-1,1)$, though I'm not sure how to establish the distribution.  My intuition is that it should be uniformly distributed.

Comment: When you say realizations, do you mean if I perform an experiment $n$ times and measure the value of the random variable $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ then I get these $\cos(\omega_0 n)$? And what would the underlying distribution be?

Comment: @gt6989b No! Assume there were one random variable $y$. What random variable $y$ would lead to such a realization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the point of this answer is not so much to answer the question posed as it is to give the question a proper formulation.  However, I find this might be a little too long for a comment, so here it goes.

---

So if $f(x)$ is the desired pdf, we'll say that 
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} f(x)
\Rightarrow f(x)=F'(x)$$
is the associated cdf.  The question we'd like to answer then is what is the closed form of $F(x)$, where $F(x)$ is the probability that $\cos\omega_0 n<x$, given that $\omega_0$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ and $n$ is uniformly selected from $\mathbb N$.

---

Here, then, is my attempt at an answer:

> **Conjecture:** let 
>   $C\subset\mathbb C = \{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$.
>   Then e$^{i \omega_0 n}$ is uniformly distributed over $C$.

Assuming the above to be the case, we note:
$$
\cos\omega_0 n < x \Rightarrow \\
\text{Re}\{\exp(i\omega_0 n)\} < x \Rightarrow\\
\arccos(x) <\text{Arg}(\exp(i\omega_0 n))< 2\pi-\arccos(x)
$$
It follows that
$$
F(x)=\frac{2\pi-2\arccos(x)}{2\pi}=1-\frac1{\pi}\arccos(x)
$$
It follows that the desired pdf should be
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}} & -1\leq x\leq 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is the answer, but I am not quite sure how to approach that conjecture.

Comment: This is (Weyl's) [equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem). Beware though that there is no such thing as a random integer uniformly selected from $\mathbb N$ (hence you might want to reformulate).

Comment: @Did Thank you for that, very good to know! I suppose I could say that this is the limiting case of an equal distribution over $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ for a "sufficiently large" $N$... but what exactly do you mean when you say there's no such thing as a random integer uniformly selected from $\mathbb N$? Why can't there be?

Comment: Because there is no probability on $\mathbb N$ which assigns equal weights to each singleton $\{n\}$. As you say, for a given set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$, one can consider the limit of the densities $n^{-1}\#(A\cap[1,n])$ when $n\to\infty$, knowing that this limit does not always exist.